# Terrible SQL performance

Tags: mysql, performance

This takes 72 seconds:

```
SELECT distinct(meters.id)
FROM meters, meters_tags, houses_tags, tags
WHERE (
        tags.name = "xxx" AND ((
            meters_tags.tag_id = tags.id AND
            meters_tags.meter_id = meters.id
          ) OR (
            houses_tags.tag_id = tags.id AND
            houses_tags.house_id = meters.house_id
          )
        )
      );
```

This takes 0.00 seconds:

```
SELECT distinct(meters.id)
FROM meters, meters_tags, houses_tags, tags
WHERE (
        tags.name = "xxx" AND ((
            meters_tags.tag_id = tags.id AND
            meters_tags.meter_id = meters.id
          )
        )
      );
```

This takes 0.00 seconds:

```
SELECT distinct(meters.id)
FROM meters, meters_tags, houses_tags, tags
WHERE (
        tags.name = "xxx" AND ((
            houses_tags.tag_id = tags.id AND
            houses_tags.house_id = meters.house_id
          )
        )
      );
```

Each of the two queries by itself take no time, but ORing them together takes 72 seconds.  I have also tried converting this to the form (query1) OR (query) instead of query0 AND ((query1) OR (query2)) and it is also very slow.

Here is the describe of the 1st (slow) query:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys                                                                                      | key                                      | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | meters_tags | index | index_meters_tags_on_tag_id_and_meter_id,index_meters_tags_on_tag_id,index_meters_tags_on_meter_id | index_meters_tags_on_tag_id_and_meter_id | 10      | NULL  |     1 | Using index; Using temporary                          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tags        | ref   | PRIMARY,tags_name                                                                                  | tags_name                                | 258     | const |     1 | Using where; Using index                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | meters      | index | PRIMARY,index_meters_on_house_id                                                                   | index_meters_on_house_id                 | 5       | NULL  | 45389 | Using index; Using join buffer                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | houses_tags | index | index_houses_tags_on_tag_id_and_house_id                                                           | index_houses_tags_on_tag_id_and_house_id | 10      | NULL  |  7158 | Using where; Using index; Distinct; Using join buffer |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

None of these tables are larger than 100k rows.  What could possibly take so long that merging these two queries takes so long when individually they can run so fast?  It seems that all of the indices I need exist since the sub queries alone are plenty fast.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but you could just do `(fastquery1) union all (fastquery2)`. This is the trick I use when the query is slowed down by `OR`s.

Comment: Thanks.  This query is being automatically generated - there are multiple clauses that can be added to the query, each separated with an AND.  Using union all breaks this pattern, but that's ok, I can special case this clause since it seems that there is no efficient way to represent this as a 'normal' clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at your combined query; it computes a cross join of houses_tags with meters_tags, sorts and eliminates duplicates, and joins that to the rest of the query. Both of yur partial queries immediately drop either houses_tags or meters_tags, and use only the othr. Hence the dramatic speed difference.

Advice: Learn and use the modern join syntax, if for no other reason than because it will help you to avoid these pathological cases until you learn to recognize them.

Comment: Would the JOIN syntax allow this query to run faster or simply make it more clear that the query is going to be slow?

Comment: The JOIN syntax allows you to recognize the cross join more easily, so you recognize more easily that the query, as written, will be non-performant. Then you know to write it another way. In this case a UNION is more performant than a cross jin.